# Why would the "Modified" column show erroneous information?

Tags: modified

A pdf document was uploaded to SharePoint on February 9th.  The "Modified" column shows the Modified date as January 8th.  If the file did not exist on SharePoint on January 8th, why would that be the Modified date?

Comment: Did you check "regional setting" for that web? If not check it first and set the correct one. `SiteSettings->Regional Settings->Time Zone and Locale`.. and let us know if it works...

Comment: @Icooley did it worked..?